# Web Scraping using nodejs : Client side event handling

Tags: node.js, client-side

I am new to nodejs.

I need to scrape the webpage by posting the credentials. 
Using nodejs can we handle the client side events?
For example: On clicking the button website redirects to next page, it here a way to handle the button click event using nodejs. how?

Comment: you are probably going to be interested in a headless browser such as [zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/)

Comment: As you suggested i have tried to install the zombia package, but end up with error... Followed the steps in https://www.npmjs.org/package/zombie